# Determinant of this special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I want to find the determinant of 
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1/(n+1) & 1/n & \cdots & 1\\  
1/(n+2) & 1/(n+1) & \cdots & 1/2\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 1/(2n+2) & 1/(2n+1) &  \cdots & 1/(n+2) 
\end{pmatrix}.$$ 
More preciesly, I hope to show that this matrix has a nonzero determinant. How I prove this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix given by $a_{ij} = 1/(i+j)$ is non-singular.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000712/matrix-given-by-a-ij-1-ij-is-non-singular). Now adapt your matrix.

Comment: Burde // Yes! Thank you so much

Comment: Your matrix has $a_{ij}=1/(i-j+n-1)$, right? It is a [Cauchy matrix](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Value_of_Cauchy_Determinant) and we know the explicit determinant formula.